# React - components being overwritten when deleted from state (based on there index)

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm having trouble with creating multiple tabs form in React. Example image:

[image]

Every new tab mounts a new component. Example code:

```
const handleAddTab = tabIndex => {
        const exampleTab = {
            name: `${Date.now()} / 16.02.2022 г.`,
            jsx: <Document />,
            deletable: true
        }

        const updatedTabs = state.tabs.map((t, i) => {
            if (tabIndex === i) t.subtabs.push(exampleTab)

            return t
        })

        setState(prev => ({
            ...prev,
            tabs: updatedTabs
        }))
    }
```

And I'm rendering those components. Example code:

```
{state.activeSubtabIndex === 0 ?
    <Documents />
    :
    getScreen().subtabs.map((s, i) =>
        i === 0 ?
            <>
            </>
            :
            <div
                style={state.activeSubtabIndex != i ? { display: 'none' } : {}}
            >
                {s.jsx}
            </div>

    )
}
```

I use getScreen() to fetch the current tab and get the subtabs. Example code:

```
const getScreen = () => {
    const typeId = query.get('type_id')
    const screen = state.tabs.find(t => t.typeId == typeId)

    return screen
}
```

The way I remove a tab is like so:

```
const handleCloseTab = (tabIndex, subtabIndex) => {
    const updatedTabs = state.tabs.filter((t, i) => {
        if (tabIndex === i) {
            t.subtabs = t.subtabs.filter((ts, i) => {
                return subtabIndex != i
            })
        }

        return t
    })

    setState(prev => ({
        ...prev,
        tabs: updatedTabs
    }))
}
```

---

**The problem is that every time I delete (for example) the first tab, the second one gets the state from the first one (based on the index it was mapped).**

Comment: How are you deleting the subtabs and what does `getScreen()` actually do?

Comment: Add a unique key to each div being output from your map

Comment: I updated my question with more info. Adding a key doesn't change anything.

Comment: Try changing `state.tabs.filter` to `state.tabs.map` in `handleCloseTab`

Comment: @apokryfos That didn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that problem by adding an extra key-value pair (deleted: false) to the **exampleTab** object

```
const handleAddTab = tabIndex => {
    const exampleTab = {
        name: `${Date.now()} / 16.02.2022 г.`,
        jsx: <Document />,
        deletable: true,
        deleted: false <====
    }

    const updatedTabs = state.tabs.map((t, i) => {
        if (tabIndex === i) t.subtabs.push(exampleTab)

        return t
   

 })

    setState(prev => ({
        ...prev,
        tabs: updatedTabs
    }))
}
```

Whenever I close a tab I'm not unmounting It and removing its data from the array. I'm simply checking if `deleted === true` and applying `style={{ display: 'none' }}` to both the tab and component. Example code:

```
{state.activeSubtabIndex === 0 ?
    <Documents />
    :
    getScreen().subtabs.map((s, i) =>
        i === 0 ?
            <>
            </>
            :
            <div
                style={state.activeSubtabIndex != i || s.deleted ? { display: 'none' } : {}}
                key={s.typeId}
            >
                {s.jsx}
            </div>
    )}
```